# How can I add an ex-mode mapping in Vim?

Tags: vim

I've just created a Vim function to replace Windows linebreaks with Unix ones. Now I want to be able to type `:linebreak` and have it run. Here's my first attempt:

```
function UseUnixLineBreaks()
  :%s/^M/\r/g
endfunction

cmap linebreak :call UseUnixLineBreaks()<CR>
```

(By the way, that `^M` is a control character - type it with `Ctrl+v Ctrl+m`)

When I try to run this by typing `:linebreak`, it does run, but it behaves oddly: each letter of the command appears in sequence, erasing the previous one. For example, I see `:l`, then `:i`, then `:n`, etc. When I type the last letter, it runs immediately.

I want the whole command to appear, so that I can see I've typed it correctly, then press enter to run it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Figured it out

Apparently what I want is not a mapping at all, but a command. So, the last line should be replaced with:

```
command Linebreak call UseUnixLineBreaks()
```

Note the capital "L" - user-defined commands must begin with a capital letter. See `:help command`.

Answer (score 2):

That's how mappings work: the replacement takes place *after* the entire mapping is entered.

To create command aliases, try the [cmdalias.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) script.

On a related note, [`:setl ff=unix`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format).